# Selecting a section of a dataframe based on an array

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe, and I'm looking to select a part of a dataframe that is equal to an element in an array I have.
This array will change within a loop. So for example here the array says "4", that means that I want to select all cases of the data frame where prediction is 4. But I'm getting an error, how can I say that it should be equal to the element in the array?

thank you in advance!

```
 print min_idx[0]
 df.prediction==min_idx[0]

 [4]

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-70-1a77e690dc3d> in <module>()
  1 print min_idx[0]
 ----> 2 df.prediction==min_idx[0]

 C:\Users\A\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in wrapper 
 (self,     other, axis)
     820             if (not lib.isscalar(lib.item_from_zerodim(other)) and
     821                     len(self) != len(other)):
 --> 822                 raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
     823 
     824             if isinstance(other, ABCPeriodIndex):

 ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

Comment: `min_idx[0]` appears to be returning a list. What happens if you try `min_idx[0][0]`?

Comment: yes!! it works! thanks!